# Removing part of files names and giving the name of one file type to another

Tags: command-line, powershell, rename, batch-rename

Suppose I have a folder with `rar` and `pdf` files for a group of people. Each person has a unique code, and he/she is associated with two files

`Full name <unique code>_dummy text to remove.rar` and `some text <unique code>_another dummy text to remove.pdf`

For example,

> `First Man 11e2345_some text to remove.rar` and `a person 11e2345_another text to remove.pdf`
>
> `Second Lady 66t7899_remove this text.rar` and `different person 66t7899_dummy text to remove.pdf`

So, I have two questions:

1- For the `rar` files, how to rename the files by removing all the text starting with the underscore after the unique code?

2- After renaming the `rar` files, how to give every `pdf` file the same name of its corresponding `rar` file by looking up the `<unique code>`?

My desired outcome should be

> `First Man 11e2345.rar` and `First Man 11e2345.pdf`
>
> `Second Lady 66t7899.rar` and `Second Lady 66t7899.pdf`

---

### Update

If the unique code has letters and numbers like `14e0123` and I know its length (e.g. `7`), how to edit this part of Karthick's code to adapt? since `$ID = $_.BaseName -replace "[^0-9]", ""`  will remove all the letters before the lookup.

```
Get-ChildItem "*.rar" | % {

    $BaseName_rar = $_.BaseName
    # Find the ID by replacing all non-digit characters in BaseName string of the 'rar' file with empty string
    # This effectively returns the ID which are the only numbers expected in the filename 
    $ID = $_.BaseName -replace "[^0-9]", ""

    Get-ChildItem "*$ID.pdf"  | % { Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($BaseName_rar + $_.Extension) }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below piece of code should help you get through.

```
$sourceFolderPath = "D:\source"
Set-Location $sourceFolderPath

# 1 Replace the part of filename from underscore character with empty string
Get-ChildItem "*.rar", "*.pdf" | % { Rename-Item $_.Fullname -NewName (($_.BaseName -replace "_.*","") + $_.Extension) }

<# 2 ForEach 'rar' file object,
    - Get the ID
    - Get the corresponding 'pdf' by ID
    - Rename the 'pdf' with BaseName of 'rar'
#>
Get-ChildItem "*.rar" | % {

    $BaseName_rar = $_.BaseName
    # If ID is just numbers
    # Find the ID by replacing all non-digit characters in BaseName string of the 'rar' file with empty string
    # This effectively returns the ID which are the only numbers expected in the filename 
     # $ID = $_.BaseName -replace "[^0-9]", ""

    # UPDATE: If ID begins with a number and has a total length of 7
    $ID = & { 
        $_.BaseName -match "(\d.{6})" | Out-Null
        $matches[0] 
    }
    
    Get-ChildItem "*$ID.pdf"  | % { Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($BaseName_rar + $_.Extension) }

}
```

#### UPDATE

Given that the ID begins with a digit and has a total length of 7, you can replace the `$ID` assignment statement to the below

```
$ID = & { 
        $_.BaseName -match "(\d.{6})" | Out-Null
        $matches[0] 
    }
```

Comment: I have one issue I forgot to mention: many times, the unique code has letters like `14e0123`. So, what should be changed here?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach that focuses on the delimiters in the text rather than length or character class. It assumes the underscore after the code is the first or only underscore in the filename.:

```
gci *.rar | ForEach{
   $NewBase = $_.BaseName.Split('_')[0]
   $Code    = $NewBase.Split(' ')[-1] 
   Rename-Item $_.FullName "$NewBase.rar"
   gci *.pdf | ? BaseName -match $Code | Rename-Item -NewName "$NewBase.pdf"
}
```

Step-by-step filename parsing demo:

```
PS C:\> $a = 'First Man 11e2345_some text to remove.rar'
PS C:\> $a.Split('_')
First Man 11e2345
some text to remove.rar
PS C:\> $a.Split('_')[0]
First Man 11e2345
PS C:\> $a.Split('_')[0].split(' ')
First
Man
11e2345
PS C:\> $a.Split('_')[0].split(' ')[-1]
11e2345
PS C:\>
```

### References

[Get-ChildItem/gci](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)

[ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-5.1)

[String.Split Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1)

[About Arrays](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-5.1)

[Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7)

[Where-Object/?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1)

[PowerShell learning resources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/more-powershell-learning?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Many thanks for this SBS demo. Would you suggest me some tutorial to learn the syntax of PowerShell by examples? For example, does `[-1]` mean that we get the last element in the array? Furthermore, I need to get myself familiar with the syntax, so I hope you can refer me to some tutorials.

Comment: Yes, ``[-1]` refers to the last element of an array. The onlilne documentation by MS is very good. I'll edit my answer to add some links. For a solid grasp of the fundamentals, get comfortable and watch [Getting Started with Microsoft PowerShell](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Getting-Started-with-Microsoft-PowerShell)